# How to convert all day events from google calendar into another timezone?

Tags: timezone, momentjs, icalendar, google-calendar-api

I want to convert events from google calendar into another timezone However, google doesn't provide timezone for calendars events which are of the all-day kind. Does anyone know a good workaround to resolve this?

Comment: Which language? What is your input? What is the expected result? What you tried so far? Please edit your question to provide further details, see here [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All day events are assumed to be in the time zone of the calendar it self.  You can determine the time zone of a calendar by preforming a [calendar.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) call

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary
```

Response

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"nfSAodzKKXewNxPMLTwQ/E756z8zuickcYzaOnj8krCN4-Pk\"",
 "id": "xxx@gmail.com",
 "summary": "xxxx@gmail.com",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen"
}
```

How to convert the dates in the events themselves to a different timezone will depend largely upon the language you are currently using.